# What is the path relativeness of the "files to include" in VS Code's search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can anyone figure out the path relativeness when doing a search in VS code and using the `files to include` input? The only way I can get this to work is to do something like `C:/Stuff/Project/src/`. My root is `C:/Stuff/Project` but if I do any combination of `/src` I also get results in some build folders like `/Project/android/src` and I adding any sensible combinations of `./src` or `../../src` or something returns no results.

[image]

Comment: Not sure where it is, but there is a setting where you can tell vscode which folders not to watch/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether it resembles an absolute path or not. If it's just a file/folder name, then it resolves to being relative to the root folder of your workspace as displayed on the **Explorer** panel. Otherwise, it gets treated as an absolute path.

For example:

[image: files to include: src]

Here, I added/opened the folder **TEMP** as the root folder.

If I put just `src` (just the folder `name`, without the leading `/` ), then it will recursively match all `name` files/folders under `/path/to/TEMP/`, no matter the depth (as shown in the image above):

- `/path/to/TEMP/src`
- `/path/to/TEMP/aaa/src`
- `/path/to/TEMP/xxx/yyy/src`

This is explained in the [Advanced search options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) docs:

> If you enter `example`, that will match every folder and file named `example` **in the workspace**

My emphasis on the "**in the workspace**" part. It's also subtlety mentioned there that this is similar to explicitly entering `**/src` to mean "*match any number of path segments, including none*" in the workspace.

> In the search view, the `**` prefix is assumed

[image: files to include: **/src]

If I put `./src` (looks like a path, with a leading `.`), this would still be relative to the workspace and it is the same as `/path/to/TEMP/src`. This is again mentioned in the docs:

> If you enter `./example`, that will match the folder `example/` **at the top level of your workspace**

[image: files to include: ./src]

If I put `src/` (with a trailing `/`), the trailing `/` is ignored and it goes back to being relative to the root folder. This is similar to just using `src`.

[image: files to include: src/]

Now, if I put `/src` (looks like a path, with a leading `/`), it is a bit different. It now gets treated as the absolute path `/src`, which is not relative anymore to the root folder. Compared to the outputs above, this yields no matches on my env because there's really nothing there.

[image: files to include: /src]

To make this less confusing, I usually just provide the file/folder `name` itself, to make it always relative to the root folder. I don't put any `/` or `.` or `..`.

To make it simpler to search for stuff, if you know the specific parent folder of the `src` folder you want to find in, you can just specify that:

[image: files to include: aaa/src]

You can even specify multiple parent folders as comma-separated names, and you can also use [`**`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) to recursively "*match any number of path segments, including none*":

[image: files to include: aaa//src, xxx//src]

Usually though, the easier way is to simply use the **files to exclude** setting instead, to exclude files/folders you *don't* want to be included in the search. You mentioned "*I also get results in some build folders like `/Project/android/src`*". So the best way here is to exclude that folder from search.

[image: files to include: src, files to exclude: aaa, xxx]

[As mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608488/vs-code-files-to-include-search#comment117748091_66608488), if you want to regularly/always exclude certain files/folders from search, there are the [`files.exclude` and `search.exclude`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options) settings:

> VS Code excludes some folders by default to reduce the number of search results that you are not interested in (for example: `node_modules`). Open [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to change these rules under the `files.exclude` and `search.exclude` section.

Comment: Thanks. Super frustrating though. There's a `src` in my root, but generated `src` folders in other folders. Having to add them all to be excluded is crazy. Why can't I just do `./src` and it knows.. ah well.